# Problems when centering items in navbar-nav when in mobile view (collapsed)

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, formatting, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollbar

Using the following CSS code, I've managed to centre the navbar-nav content in my navbar within my navbar, in

```
/* @media (min-width:768px) {  */ Note this comment

.navbar > .container {
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar-header,.navbar-brand,.navbar .navbar-nav,.navbar .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.collapse.navbar-collapse {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block!important;
    width: auto;
    clear: none;
}
/* } */ Note this comment
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>Link3 (Dropdown)</span><b class = "caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

1st problem:

Now, when you view this navbar on your computer in its expanded entirety, it works fine - the items are centred and whatnot. However, when you collapse the kit and caboodle, the 3-icon-bar button is always active and there's no way of hiding the items in the navbar.

2nd problem (ties in with first):

Not to mention, when you click it, it switches between two states - one which causes the Link-3 dropdown menu to overlap Link 4, resulting in another scroll bar to navigate between the sublinks (this state I don't want) - and the other state causes there to be no scroll bar, instead resulting in the dropdown menu overlapping the bottom of the navbar (this I want). Therefore, what I'm trying to do is making it so that the two states are: 1. everything is hidden, 2. Link 3 when hovered over doesn't result in a scroll bar.

3rd problem:

Also, when you click on Link 3, Link 3 gets pushed up, out of its alignment with Links 1 and 2 - I'd just like for it to respond as if nothing happened - you're still just hovering.

Last problem:

This has to do strictly because of the commented out part in the CSS code above, but as a result of this code, the content in the footer navbar (which you can't see) is also centered. For this problem, I just want an explanation because once again, that @media (min-width:768px) stuff does it.

Note: all these problems arise because of @media (min-width:768px) {} being commented out in the CSS. If you suggest uncommenting the commented out part, it's fine by me, but when you go to the mobile view, the formatting of the items in the navbar isn't the same as it is when that part is commented out. Plus, you still have the scroll bar for the dropdown. There's probably an easier way of fixing this all by keeping in the part that I commented out and instead adding something to the CSS that applies similar formatting to the items when the navbar is collapsed without going through all the aforementioned problems, but I can't seem to get it. If you can though, thanks so much.

I know this is a lot to ask but tackle what you can, and thanks in advance! And if there's some additional code you need from me to better understand wtf is going here, just lemme know.

And I'm using Bootstrap 3.2.0.

Comment: I'm confused on what you are asking for. This functions as it should? Check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/KXje2/3/

Comment: You're asking why the hamburger button is popping up and the nav-bar links are going away?

Comment: Really sorry for the late reply, sorry for not including this in the CSS above, because it plays a pretty big role. The way I set it up is so that when the link is hovered over, the menu drops down, due to this code: .navbar-nav > li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block; } in my CSS. Now when you run the code, a scroll bar pops up when you try to navigate over the links stemming from Link 3, overlapping Link 4. That's my problem: how to make it so there is no scroll bar, and have the drop down menu overlap Link 4.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for in your question? I am extremely clueless.

Comment: There is no scroll bar appearing... What browser are you using?

Comment: Yeah, the code now looks like http://jsfiddle.net/KXje2/5/, and you can see that the dropdown menu is restricted by the border of the navbar, I want the menu to overlap it and thus eliminate the scroll bar. Does that make sense?

Comment: Really? I'm using chrome and I'm getting a scroll bar for those sublinks.

Comment: I seee it now... give me a moment...

Comment: No problem, I got time.

Comment: Try this one? http://jsfiddle.net/KXje2/6/ I do want to mention as well... I advise not to use a hovering drop down menu.. solely because if you want someone to hover while on a mobile device, it's not as clean and efficient as you would expect it to be. Make it user-friendly. And realistically, it will be very rare that someone will have a small screen and be on a PC. Small screens should be built around mobile devices, and touch friend mobile devices will really never allow you to hover, which means you should not implement this in your design. But, it is your design :)

Comment: You know, yeah you're right. F this, I'm a just get rid of that hovering feature and my life will be ten times easier, lol. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: If you could up-vote/check my answer as right that would be fantastic!

Comment: For sure, lol, I was trying to up-vote your comment before, I'm a noob.

Comment: Haha no worries, that's awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your design, you are using the following CSS:

```
.navbar-nav > li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Which is creating that scrollbar/hover deal. In all reality, as discussed in the comments, it may not be a great idea to implement this in a mobile design because hovering is something that is not possible to achieve with touch-only devices.

**In other words**

The conclusion is to just take out this feature and continue with an easy drop-down. You, however, still have a drop down menu for your desktop devices. An example is below.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KXje2/7/)**

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe do like I do and drill down to the structure you want hidden. Maybe when it's hidden the code on the page changes so snag that new code structure to hide it?

An example I have on my website is:

```
div h3 span.HeaderImg img {
    visibility:hidden
}
```

Not sure if this helps but it's what came to mind. All my other images have the default padding and structure in place but instead of going through the code and trying to delete that single image I am simply able to hide it.

**EDIT:**
 Maybe try it with `float:left` to give it some structure. You can still `text-align:center` with `float:left` by setting `width:100%`. I have some similar code on my website that may help you as well. You are free to use it or modify it if it helps:

```
.menulist li:hover li ul, .menulist li li:hover li ul {
    top:-999em
}
.menulist {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:3px double #20C5B5
}
.menulist ul {
    z-index:1000;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
.menulist li {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
.menulist li a {
    display:block;
    margin-left:13px;
    padding-top:.333em;
    padding-bottom:.333em;
    font-size:large;
    color:#20C5B5
}
.menulist li li {
    height:auto;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
.menulist li li a {
    padding:0 16px
}
.menulist li ul {
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    width:13em;
    left:-999em;
    margin-left:-1px;
    padding:4px 0;
    color:#FFF
}
.menulist li:hover ul {
    top:3em;
    left:.333em
}
.menulist li li:hover ul, #menulist li li li:hover ul {
    left:190px;
    top:0
}
```

Comment: Oh cool, your float: left + width: 100% method at least got rid of the sub-scroll-bar. Unfortunately, I'm new to HTML and CSS, so I'm not able to make the best use of the code you gave me atm, but thanks for sharing your ideas. Your effort is appreciated. I'll continue to try and play with it.

Comment: Instead of `navbar-header,.navbar-brand,.navbar .navbar-nav,.navbar .navbar-nav` There are multiple classes put on each segment so you can maybe drill down from each segment through those classes. Something like `.navbar-toggle.navHeaderCollapse span {definitions}` or `.navbar-toggle span.level1 {definitions}` and `.navbar-toggle span.level2 {definitions}`. Hope this helps

Comment: +1 for being helpful! However, for future reference, try to post relevant code pertaining to the situation. We want to use SO as the most effective QA website possible. Just remember to be precise, concise, and to the point. We appreciate your helpfulness, just try to make it more relevant in the future.